How to identify rows that add up (sum) to a specific amount
I am trying to identify rows in a specific dataset with a dollar amount column that sum up to a specific amount.  I know the amount and the amount of rows that add up to that amount.
Parameters:
4 records to sum up to $15.68
dataset is > 450k records
so is there a way to find 4 rows that sum up to $15.68
say the table has a unique Identifier for each row called ID and then a corresponding amount column
ID     Amount
22     $11.55
33     $5.55
44     $3.33
55     $2.33
66     $1.11
77     $.99
88     $-1.77
91     $0.00
99     $-5.00
100    $3.33
111    $4.44
122    $5.00
133    $4.00
144    $2.24

so I am looking to get a result set of the last 4 records out of this sample set.

Please clarify: 1. Must the result be four consecutive rows (ordered by ID) as in your example? 2. Do you allow a row to appear more than once in the result set?

Use INNER JOIN to join the table to itself 4 times and join so that the values are in ascending order so that you do not repeated combinations in different orders or rows repeatedly joined to themselves:
SELECT d1.id AS id1,
       d1.amount AS amount1,
       d2.id AS id2,
       d2.amount AS amount2,
       d3.id AS id3,
       d3.amount AS amount3,
       d4.id AS id4,
       d4.amount AS amount4
FROM   data d1
       INNER JOIN data d2
       ON (d1.id < d2.id)
       INNER JOIN data d3
       ON (d2.id < d3.id)
       INNER JOIN data d4
       ON (d3.id < d4.id)
WHERE  d1.amount + d2.amount + d3.amount + d4.amount = 15.68;

Which outputs:



ID1
AMOUNT1
ID2
AMOUNT2
ID3
AMOUNT3
ID4
AMOUNT4




111
4.44
122
5
133
4
144
2.24




If you want the values as rows then UNPIVOT:
SELECT id,
       amount
FROM   (
  SELECT d1.id AS id1,
         d1.amount AS amount1,
         d2.id AS id2,
         d2.amount AS amount2,
         d3.id AS id3,
         d3.amount AS amount3,
         d4.id AS id4,
         d4.amount AS amount4
  FROM   data d1
         INNER JOIN data d2
         ON (d1.id < d2.id)
         INNER JOIN data d3
         ON (d2.id < d3.id)
         INNER JOIN data d4
         ON (d3.id < d4.id)
  WHERE  d1.amount + d2.amount + d3.amount + d4.amount = 15.68
)
UNPIVOT (
  (amount, id) FOR type IN (
    (amount1, id1) AS 1,
    (amount2, id2) AS 2,
    (amount3, id3) AS 3,
    (amount4, id4) AS 4
  )
);

Which outputs:



ID
AMOUNT




111
4.44


122
5


133
4


144
2.24




You can also solve it with a recursive query:
WITH hierarchy (id1, amount1, id2, amount2, id3, amount3, id4, amount4, lvl, total) AS (
  SELECT id, amount,
         CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), CAST(NULL AS NUMBER),
         CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), CAST(NULL AS NUMBER),
         CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), CAST(NULL AS NUMBER),
         1, amount
  FROM   data
 UNION ALL
  SELECT h.id1,
         h.amount1,
         CASE lvl + 1 WHEN 2 THEN d.id     ELSE h.id2 END,
         CASE lvl + 1 WHEN 2 THEN d.amount ELSE h.amount2 END,
         CASE lvl + 1 WHEN 3 THEN d.id     ELSE h.id3 END,
         CASE lvl + 1 WHEN 3 THEN d.amount ELSE h.amount3 END,
         CASE lvl + 1 WHEN 4 THEN d.id     ELSE h.id4 END,
         CASE lvl + 1 WHEN 4 THEN d.amount ELSE h.amount4 END,
         lvl + 1, amount + total
  FROM   data d
         INNER JOIN hierarchy h
         ON COALESCE(h.id3, h.id2, h.id1) < d.id AND h.lvl < 4
)
SELECT id, amount
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   hierarchy
  WHERE  lvl = 4
  AND    total = 15.68
)
UNPIVOT (
  (amount, id) FOR type IN (
    (amount1, id1) AS 1,
    (amount2, id2) AS 2,
    (amount3, id3) AS 3,
    (amount4, id4) AS 4
  )
);

Which also outputs:



ID
AMOUNT




111
4.44


122
5


133
4


144
2.24



fiddle

One method is to cartesian join your data to itself four times to create every possible combination of four rows, then add up the amounts, find the combinations that total your target amount, then re-pivot back to the original rows:
WITH data AS (select 22 id,11.55 amount from dual union all
select 33,5.55 from dual union all
select 44,3.33 from dual union all
select 55,2.33 from dual union all
select 66,1.11 from dual union all
select 77,.99 from dual union all
select 88,-1.77 from dual union all
select 91,0.00 from dual union all
select 99,-5.00 from dual union all
select 100,3.33 from dual union all
select 111,4.44 from dual union all
select 122,5.00 from dual union all
select 133,4.00 from dual union all
select 144,2.24 from dual)
SELECT DISTINCT data.*
  FROM (SELECT d1.id id1,
               d2.id id2,
               d3.id id3,
               d4.id id4,
               d1.amount + d2.amount + d3.amount + d4.amount total_amount
          FROM data d1,
               data d2,
               data d3,
               data d4) x,
       data
 WHERE x.total_amount = 15.68
   AND data.id IN (x.id1,x.id2,x.id3,x.id4)

You can probably also use a hierarchical query (CONNECT BY...) and a windowing function to aggregate along the hierarchy path. That would be more flexible as it wouldn't be structurally hard-coded to exactly 4 values.

This will join rows to themselves so if you have a single row with the amount 15.68/4 then it will be matched fiddle

@MT0: Good point, but in my opinion the request is not clear about this. The OP will have to decide whether they want to allow a row multiple times in the result set or not.

There is no need to use performance costly multiple self joins you could keep it simple using Sum() Over() and LAG() Over() analytic functions with windowing clause (... Rows Between ...).
Cardinality/Cost is 1/34
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    tbl AS 
      ( Select 22 ID,  11.55 AMOUNT From Dual Union All
        Select 33, 5.55 From Dual Union All
        Select 44, 3.33 From Dual Union All
        Select 55, 2.33 From Dual Union All
        Select 66, 1.11 From Dual Union All
        Select 77, .99 From Dual Union All
        Select 88, -1.77 From Dual Union All
        Select 91, 0.00 From Dual Union All
        Select 99, -5.00 From Dual Union All
        Select 100, 3.33 From Dual Union All
        Select 111, 4.44 From Dual Union All
        Select 122, 5.00 From Dual Union All
        Select 133, 4.00 From Dual Union All
        Select 144, 2.24 From Dual
      ), 

The code uses parameters and it should give the result for any number of rows (not just 4) and any sum you bound to the parameters.
... create cte (named it calc) to get sum of every :NumRowsParameter (4) rows along  with starting and ending IDs that summed result is equal :SumRowsParameter (15.68)
    calc AS
      ( Select  *
        From    ( Select ID, AMOUNT,
                         Sum(AMOUNT) OVER(Order By ID Rows Between :NumRowsParameter - 1 Preceding And Current Row) "SUM_ROWS",
                         LAG(ID, :NumRowsParameter - 1) Over(Order By ID) "ID_START", ID "ID_END"
                  From   tbl
                  Order By ID
                )
        Where   SUM_ROWS = :SumRowsParameter
      )

... inner join your table to above cte and filter the result with Join's ON clause
--     M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT       tbl.* 
FROM         calc
INNER JOIN   tbl ON(tbl.ID Between calc.ID_START And calc.ID_END)
ORDER BY     tbl.ID

/*    R e s u l t :      ( for :NumRowsParameter = 4 and :SumRowsParameter = 15.68 )
 ID  AMOUNT
---  ------
111    4.44
122       5
133       4
144    2.24  */

/*    R e s u l t :      ( for :NumRowsParameter = 5 and :SumRowsParameter = 13.31 )
 ID  AMOUNT
---  ------
 33    5.55
 44    3.33
 55    2.33
 66    1.11
 77    0.99  */

/*    R e s u l t :      ( for :NumRowsParameter = 1 and :SumRowsParameter = 3.33 )
 ID  AMOUNT
---  ------
 44    3.33
100    3.33    */


You think that the OP is looking for four consecutive rows. I don't. Well, the desired result in the request is four consecutive rows, so the OP should clarify whether this just happens to be so or is part of the task.

@ThorstenKettner Yes, that's how I  understood it. I might be wrong, of course. It is not explicitely stated about that, but if it is not consecutive then the sample data &  expected result SHOULD be different.
